# In Laravel, why does "return response()->json([])" take 700 ms longer than "return []"

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In Laravel, I can return from a controller like this:

```php
return response()->json(["name" => "Bob"])
```

Or I can return like this:

```php
return ["name" => "Bob"]
```

Both of these return the same thing, but the first one takes about 700ms longer.  Does anybody know why and how to fix this?

Extra details:  Laravel version 8.  I'm using Sail (Docker) on my laptop.

More details: I measured the time of the request with Chrome developer tools. I went back and forth a number of times, between the two different ways, with consistent results.

If you want to see the project, here is a stripped down version of it: https://github.com/tkoop/slow_laravel_response

Comment: How did you measure this? Is this happening for the first requests after `sail up` or for all requests?

Comment: Measured with Chrome developer tools. I went back and forth a number of times, with consistent results.

Comment: Without more details (system specs like OS, docker version and app specs like packages, middlewares, before/after termination callbacks, loggers..) I would suggest to use some profiler like blackfire (or similar) to identify where it hangs. Another hand-made solution would be to add dd()'s before and after all request middlewares and all shutdown callbacks.

Comment: Is there a chance to create a minimal reproducible example repository and share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon inspecting your project, the package [`codeat3/blade-google-material-design-icons`](https://github.com/codeat3/blade-google-material-design-icons) is the culprit. It depends on [`blade-ui-kit/blade-icons`](https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons) and according to the readme file, the problem is [caching](https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons#caching). You can either run `php artisan icons:cache` (it will still slow down the response by ~100ms) or disable Blade components (no noticeable slow down) if you don't need them:

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=blade-icons

# /config/blade-icons.php
return [
    'components' => [
        'disabled' => true,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem need some more details, so far;
First, set up this tool: https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork.
Then, get the specific analysis in the timeline section.
This will give more technical details, and It's going to be understandable why first response is slow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After installing Clockwork, it tells me that when I return a plain object, Controller takes 15 ms (13ms self, and 2ms children).  When I return using response->json, Controller takes 1086 ms (1070 ms self, and 16 ms children).  I've gone back and forth, and the times are always similar.

Comment: In my perspective:
1) I would suggest to install a fresh new Laravel project, if it's possible.
2) Check if there is something like Queues function. See this docs for more detail about Queues : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues
3) response function trigger a huge amount of data.

Comment: We already have tried making a new install and copying stuff over--that's how we discovered this.  We are not using the queue at all.  The response data is identical either way.